# How to add a closing bracket at end of each line using sed?

Tags: unix, sed, end-of-line

I'm trying to add `}` at end of each **line** using `sed`

i use the following command:
    `sed -i 's/$/}/g' test.txt`

But it adds `}` at end of the **file** instead. What is the correct command?

I am using kali subsystem on windows 10 is that the problem? how can I fix this?

Comment: This command is correct, it gives me `}` at end of each line. Try `dos2unix file_name` to see if it has wrong formatting.

Comment: maybe real kali and kali in windows 10 are different?

Answer (score -2):

You should use line end character for replace part in sed statement.

Example:

```
$ cat data 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$ cat data |sed -r 's#$#}$#g'
1}$
2}$
3}$
4}$
5}$
6}$
7}$
8}$
9}$
10}$
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't agree with you, he wants to add '}' char to end of each line.